# d3.js: Pie Chart Layout - Adjusting the Angle to Create Shutter Effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have been tasked with recreating an interactive piechart with d3.js - The angle on the segments of my pie chart don't begin in the middle of the pie chart (see image below) and are slightly off. What is the best way to draw the shutter effect I want? You can see where I have got to with my code below.

**JS Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vh6nwtpb/3/

**The effect I'm trying to gain:**
[image]

**JS Code**

```
  // Data Used for this example...
  var dataSet1 = [
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 1", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#252d38", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 2", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#173c59", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 3", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#223343", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 4", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#20364b", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 5", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#1d3853", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 6", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#015190", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 7", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#144162", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 8", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#0f436a", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 9", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#0f4873", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 10", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#0d4b7c", seghovcolour: "#005190"},
    {legendLabel: "Legend String 11", magnitude: 9.09, link: "https://www.uk-cpi.com/", segcolour: "#0f5086", seghovcolour: "#005190"}
  ];

  function drawPie( pieName, dataSet, selectString, colors, margin, outerRadius, innerRadius, sortArcs ) {
    var colorScale = d3.scale.category20c();
    var canvasWidth = 620;
    var canvasHeight = 0;
    var innerRadius = 150;
    var outerRadius = 300;
    var pieWidthTotal = outerRadius * 2;
    var pieCenterX = outerRadius + margin/2;
    var pieCenterY = outerRadius + margin/2;
    var legendVerticalOffset = outerRadius - margin;
    var legendTextOffset = 20;
    var textVerticalSpace = 20;
    var pieDrivenHeight = outerRadius*2 + margin*2;
    var legendTextDrivenHeight = (dataSet.length * textVerticalSpace) + margin*2;

    // Autoadjust Canvas Height
    if (pieDrivenHeight >= legendTextDrivenHeight)
    {
      canvasHeight = pieDrivenHeight;
    }
    else
    {
      canvasHeight = legendTextDrivenHeight;
    }

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(dataSet, function(d) { return d.magnitude; })]).rangeRound([0, pieWidthTotal]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, dataSet.length]).range([0, (dataSet.length * 20)]);

    // HOVER COLOUR
    var synchronizedMouseOver = function() {
      var arc = d3.select(this);
      var indexValue = arc.attr("index_value");

      var arcSelector = "." + "pie-" + pieName + "-arc-" + indexValue;
      var selectedArc = d3.selectAll(arcSelector);
      var colorValue = selectedArc.attr("color_hover");
      selectedArc.style("fill", colorValue);
    };

    var synchronizedMouseOut = function() {
      var arc = d3.select(this);
      var indexValue = arc.attr("index_value");

      var arcSelector = "." + "pie-" + pieName + "-arc-" + indexValue;
      var selectedArc = d3.selectAll(arcSelector);
      var colorValue = selectedArc.attr("fill");
      selectedArc.style("fill", colorValue);

    };


    var tweenPie = function (b) {
      b.innerRadius = 0;
      var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }

    // Create a drawing canvas...
    var canvas = d3.select(selectString)
      .append("svg:svg") //create the SVG element inside the <body>
        .data([dataSet]) //associate our data with the document
        .attr("width", canvasWidth) //set the width of the canvas
        .attr("height", canvasHeight) //set the height of the canvas
        .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold our pie chart
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + pieCenterX + "," + pieCenterY + ")") // Set center of pie

// Define an arc generator. This will create <path> elements for using arc data.
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(innerRadius) // Causes center of pie to be hollow
        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

// Define a pie layout: the pie angle encodes the value of dataSet.
// Since our data is in the form of a post-parsed CSV string, the
// values are Strings which we coerce to Numbers.
      var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d) { return d.magnitude; })
        .sort(function(a, b) {if (sortArcs==1) { return b.magnitude - a.magnitude; } else { return null; } });

      // Select all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
      var arcs = canvas.selectAll("g.slice")
      // Associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle,
      // endAngle and value properties)
      .data(pie)
      // This will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated
      // with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
      // Create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text>      // element associated with each slice)
        .enter().append("svg:a")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.data.link; })
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "slice")    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
          // Set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
          // This creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
      .style("stroke", "White" )
      .attr("d", arc);

    arcs.append("svg:path")

      // Set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
      // This creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function


      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return d.data.segcolour; })
      .attr("color_hover", function(d, i) { return d.data.seghovcolour; })


      .attr("index_value", function(d, i) { return "index-" + i; })
      .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "pie-" + pieName + "-arc-index-" + i; })
      .style("stroke", "White" )
      .attr("d", arc)
      .on('mouseover', synchronizedMouseOver)
      .on("mouseout", synchronizedMouseOut)
      .transition()
      .ease("")
      .duration(2000)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 0; })
      .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

    // Add a magnitude value to the larger arcs, translated to the arc centroid and rotated.
    arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; }).append("svg:text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
        //we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius; // Set Outer Coordinate
        d.innerRadius = innerRadius; // Set Inner Coordinate
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
      })
      .style("fill", "White")
      .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.magnitude; });

    // Computes the angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.
    function angle(d) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
      return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
    }

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect, the inner arc of each piece has to be offset by a few radians.

Unfortunately, this is not possible with just D3. The issue is that we can only specify the [start and end angles](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arc_startAngle) of the whole arc. We can't specify the start and end angles of just the inner arc or just the outer arc.

If we check [D3's `arc` source code responsible for drawing the arc](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/e8a2dc6da0a8557ff582629cc48908146bf45e84/src/arc.js#L216), we can tweak the line:

```
else context.arc(0, 0, r0, a10, a00, cw);
```

to:

```
else {
  var offsetDegrees = 10,
      offsetRadians = offsetDegrees * Math.PI / 180;
  context.arc(0, 0, r0, a10 + offsetRadians, a00 + offsetRadians, cw);
}
```

and achieve the desired effect.

Unfortunately, this change will mess up with the calculation of the arc centroid and probably a bunch of other functionality.

Changing source code is never a good practice, this effect should either be proposed in the `d3-shape` library or implemented as a D3 plugin.